# Display $_POST values from TXT file in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have a form that gets submitted to the next page. Then on this next page there is an include command for a text(TXT) file. But I want to display the form data at certain points in this text(TXT) file.

I tried to have place `$_POST["firstname"]` and `$_POST["surname"]` in the txt file for their names to appear, but the actual text `$_POST["firstname"]` and  `$_POST["surname"]` appear on the website instead of the values of those fields. Is there a way to display the values from the text file when ever the `firstname` and `surname` appear?

The rest of the txt file will never change. Just the names will. I have tried googling but all I have found is how to write to a txt file or read the whole file. All I want is to display the file and change those values.

Comment: where is your code?  what doesn't work?

Comment: PHP won't get executed if it's added in a .txt file.

Comment: Are there known tokens in the TEXT file that has places for the firstname and surname, such as `{{FIRST_NAME}}`? If so, you could always do a simple `str_replace($textFile, '{{FIRST_NAME}}', $_POST['firstname'])`

Comment: You should mark up inline code with `\`backticks\``, not **\*\*bold\*\***.

Comment: Hi Rob, I can add tokens for them to be replaced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options here. One option would be instead of storing the data in a text file, store it in the PHP file. I doubt you want to go this route, though, and there's another option.

Essentially what you'd be doing is just using PHP's built-in replace functions to get rid of values you have in the text files and replace them with the values from the previous page. You could really achieve such a thing by doing something like:

```
$search = array("{firstname}", "{surname}");
$replace = array($_POST['firstname'], $_POST['surname']);

$file = file_get_contents("data.txt"); //notice `file_get_contents` instead of include

echo str_replace($search, $replace, $file);
```

In the above, we're using [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead of an include, and simply replacing everything we find in the `$search` array with the `$replace` array. Note that you'd have to have set values in the text files that you want to replace. For example, `{firstname}` may be repeated throughout the file so it can later be replaced with "John," and `{lastname}` with "Doe".

Comment: @Dino If my solution worked as desired, please select the outlined checkbox under the voting controls to accept this answer.

Comment: So Nile, I assume if I wanted to change a couple more phrases I could just add that to the search and replace? Further to the above. If I wanted to add some tags for CSS in the TXT file could that also work? I'm not a developer by trade and can only test this out when I get home.

Comment: @Dino Yes, if you put markup/style inside the text file and it's outputted to the page, the client should render it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple template class that will easily do what you are looking for.

1. Copy/paste the [class_simple_template.php](http://pastebin.com/Zq9mfsdw) contents
2. Then use the class like so:

   //include the class file

   include_once('class_simple_template.php);

   // instantiate the template object

   $template = new simple_template('/path/to/directory/containing/template/file/', $debug=0);

   // setup the array that will contain the placeholder names from the template file and their associated replacement values:

   $template_data = array(
       'firstname' => $_POST['firstname'],
       'surname' => $_POST['surname']
   );

   // load the template file and interpolate the placeholder "tokens" with the actual values:

   $final_result = $template->return_parsed_file('your_text_file.txt', $template_data, $email=false);

   echo $final_result;

The contents of 'your_text_file.txt' would use the placeholders like this:

Hello {firstname} {surname},

Thank you {firstname}, we really appreciate....

etc ...